# Best theming practice for leanest possible code?

Tags: 8, theming

I am about to upgrade a website from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 and with that, I am thinking to move away from Bootstrap to reduce page sizes. I am thinking to go three different routes with this one:

1. Use a smaller basetheme than bootstrap and build a subtheme. It will be easier for me to build. However, I am worried about having unnecessary code and increased page load times.
2. Build a theme from scratch. But my theming skills are not good and it will take so much time for me to come up with something good. But it has the advantage of being extremely small and page loads will be good I suppose.
3. Pick a drupal 8 theme that is closest to what I have in my mind and change it. However, I never realized how difficult it is to find a fluid full width simple clean small drupal 8 theme that is not dependent on a large basethemes.

What might be the best practice for theming, in someone who prefers to keep things as small as possible? How much of a difference will building from a basetheme cause to pageload times?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is very broad but in general its always easier to finish a a project with a themebase that you are familiar with ... and the overhead of using bootstrap or any other themebase is not that great over a leaner theme.

Still if you know enough you can just load the boostrap javascript libraries that are needed and not all of them.  Maybe bootstrap theme project already has an option but at least drupal core has ways to exclude .js or .css files that are not needed.

Also you have to consider the overhead of time it might take to create your own responsive solutions for common layout problems which bootstrap and other css frameworks have already implemented and have been tested by many people.

Perhaps you should test any other base themes from drupal.org and see which one feels more comfortable to extend based on your theming experience ... perhaps you can also try out [bootstrap 4 base theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio) as a starting point which is probably a leaner themebase than bs3.

Answer (score 0):

Take or build a theme that's based on [Bourbon Neat](http://neat.bourbon.io/). In contrast to Bootstrap it won't pollute your markup with a shipload of classes.

[Basic](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic) (includes Neat 2.0) and [Neato](https://www.drupal.org/project/neato) (includes Neat 1.0). But if I remember it right both have Drupal's "Classy" core theme as base theme. Which already provides quite an amount of predefined classes (as the name suggests). If you would like it even leaner you could start your own sub-theme of Drupal's "Stable" core theme.